# How to get nearby places from Google Places?

Tags: angular

I am Developing a Project which Required Nearby Schools , My Technology is Angular 2 , I have tried below Google API  Http Request in Client Page

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=lat,long&radius=5000&type=school&key=<my-API-KEY>'
```

But while Requesting this API i am Getting Error of CORS  like

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location-42.60…=5000&type=school&sensor=false&key=.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://mysite.something' is therefore not allowed access.

So i need a Solution to Enable the CORS Service in my Http Request or i need an Alternate Solution to Get Nearby School based on Lat Long in Angular 2

Comment: What headers are you sending along with the request?

Comment: i am not sending any headers

Comment: anyone found this problem solution

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when you try to access google place API from non ssl certified sites. and Also now its mandatory to use `https//maps.googleapis.com` in your application to get data from google place api.

This change made in mid of 2016 and for that, you need to place your site in ssl and then it will be accessible

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need an API key to access the API.

Check this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location-42.60

You can get your API key from [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). You have to enable and create credentials for the API which is required for your application. You can also specify the host site from which you can this API to be accessed.

Secondly, you may implement a store locator to satisfy your application requirements. Check this: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

P.S. Google API are not completely free. They'll give you the pre-defined number of hits/access to the APIs. Most of them are restricted to 1000 free requests a day. You can always extend this limit by paying for your extra hits, which I guess is 0.5$/1000 requests.